# Java, newbie needs help using command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line

I've been googling for hours and haven't managed to figure out what I'm doing wrong, sorry I'm really bad at java!

I have a basic 2d graphics program that draws a grid. At first I used set values to set the size of the grid. Now I have been set the task of replacing my set values with values entered at the command line. I just can't get it to work.  Please could you look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class W1Graphics extends JFrame



{
MyPanel myVeryOwnPanel;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    W1Graphics w = new W1Graphics();
    w.setVisible(true);

}

public W1Graphics(String[] args)
{

    String a = args[0];
    String b = args[1];
    int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(b);

    setTitle("Jimmy Hill");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,300);
    setLocation(300,300);
    myVeryOwnPanel = new MyPanel(x, y);
    add(myVeryOwnPanel);
}

 }
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: The command line arguments come from the main method

Comment: This shouldn't compile - you're trying to create an instance of `W1Graphics` using a default constructor it doesn't have. It looks like you want to be passing `args` in, i.e. `W1Graphics w = new W1Graphics(args);`.

Comment: Thank you so very much, can't believe I didn't realise that. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line arguments are the ones given to the main method not the W1Graphics method.

This code below:

```
String a = args[0];
    String b = args[1];
    int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
```

should be in your main method. And you should then pass the x and y parameters to your W1Graphics constructor.

EX:

public W1Graphics(int x, int y)
{

```
setTitle("Jimmy Hill");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(500,300);
setLocation(300,300);
myVeryOwnPanel = new MyPanel(x, y);
add(myVeryOwnPanel);
```

}

and of course in your main method say something like this:

```
String a = args[0];
    String b = args[1];
    int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
    W1Graphics w = new W1Graphics(x, y);
        w.setVisible(true);
```

**EDIT**: or of course pass args to your constructor! but it is better programming practice to leave parsing command line args for you main method so that you separate the method functionality. You don't want to handle command line argument exceptions in the W1Graphics constructor but in the main method before you even call it.

Answer (score 1):

On your line: `W1Graphics w = new W1Graphics();` your calling a constructor with no arguments. What you want to do is call the constructor which takes `String[]` type. Change your line where you create the W1Graphics object to `W1Graphics w = new W1Graphics(args);`